Долгая установка Visual Studio. Очень долго устанавливаются пакеты
В первый раз когда скачивал VS, то было все быстро и норм. Сейчас все медленно и т.д. Я смотрю у других и думаю что возможно проблема в диске. Хотя у меня ssd и он не плохо показывает себя в других скачках. В VS я выбрал консольные приложение C# и unity. Кто знает с чем это связанно ? Интернет, пк норм

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Неизвестно, с чем связано.

Откройте task manager и посмотрите. Вполне возможно параллельно с установкой в фоне яростно вкалывают антивирус и индексатор файлов

Если устанавливаете VisualStudio вместе с Unity, то там могут быть проблемы с установкой. Лучше самостоятельно установить VisualStudio с сайта Майкрософт и уже потом ставить Unity.
